# Skip given vertical space accross pages if needed

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

I would like to leave a vertical space of a given length, say 10cm, in my tex document. In fact, I want to leave enough space in a proof environment for the proof to be written at hand once the document is printed...

I tried `\vspace` and its starred version but the space does not span across pages when there is not enough space remaining.

Is there a way to leave exactly 10cm vertical space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\vspace*{10cm}` will leave 10cm vertical space, but this will not be split across the pages.  However, if you instead leave 10 times 1cm of space, it will be split (20 times 5mm might be even better).  To make you life easier, instead of typing `\vspace*` many times, you can use a loop, for example

```
\newcount\Scount
\Scount=0
\loop\vspace*{1cm}\par\goodbreak\advance\Scount by 1 \ifnum\Scount<10\repeat
```

Comment: Nice! I also tried inserting 10 `\vspace*{1cm}` but didn't have the `\par\goodbreak` part!

Answer (score 1):

One can also declare a new maccro to accomplish this task :

```
\newcount\cnt
\newcommand{\myVSpace}[1]{ %Call this maccro to get a vertical space of #1 cm
    \cnt=0
    \loop\vspace*{\dimexpr #1 cm /10  \relax} \advance\Scount by 1 \ifnum\Scount<10\repeat
}
```